Why isn't adjustNothing applied in Components ModalBottomSheet?
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = {
                showDeleteUserSheet = false
            },
            sheetState = sheetState
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Sample title",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = "text",
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.white.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

                    TextField(
                        hint = "Sample hint1"
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

                    TextField(
                        hint = "Sample hint2"
                    )
                }

                Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)) {
                    Button() {

                    }

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

                    Button() {
                    }

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
                }
            }
        }

When you click in a text field and the keyboard appears, the two buttons at the bottom also move to the top with the keyboard.
I don't set up windowSoftInputMode, so I'm in adjustNothing state, and this only happens in ModalBottomSheet
It doesn't happen inside other normal columns and components  :(
If anyone knows anything about this, please help
It's very nice of you.
